# RDP from windows to ubuntu not working

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop

When using the default RDP connection for windows 10 to connect to my ubuntu 20 laptop, I can only see the terminal. Everything I open through the terminal opens on my laptop screen. How do I fix this? I can only open the terminal on RDP by opening it on my ubuntu laptop with nothing else open I only have a black screen before that.

[image: See here]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install an RDP server on Ubuntu.

See the article
[How to Install Xrdp Server (Remote Desktop) on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/)
on how to install the `xrdp` package.

In a nutshell, you need to do:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

And add the xrdp user to the “ssl-cert” group :

```
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
```

See the article for details.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. I get a black screen on my windows machine, meaning I have to open the terminal on my ubuntu laptop. Anything I open outside of the terminal on my windows machine shows on my ubuntu laptop screen rather than the rdp screen on my windows machine. The VNC option doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Have you gone through the linked article from the beginning?